# Any Real Life Uses for JMeter's BeanShell Timer?

Tags: jmeter

I'm almost certain I did not skip any website that mentions BeanShell Timer but could not find a real use of it. Anyone really needed it in any situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you need to add a delay based on an edge condition which is not covered by other timers i.e. [Constant Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer) or [Gaussian Random Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Gaussian_Random_Timer) or [Uniform Random Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Uniform_Random_Timer) or whatever.

Example 1:

- you have submitted a request and it returns "pending" status
- according to your application design you can retry this request in, say, 5 seconds
- so if previous sampler response contains `pending` you need to wait for 5 seconds. In this case it would be feasible to consider using Beanshell Timer

Example 2:

- you need to implement a distribution which is not covered by existing timers, i.e. [Bernoulli distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) or [Rademacher distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rademacher_distribution) which are not covered by the existing timers.

So you should be using scripting-based timers when you need to produce delay based on a custom condition which cannot be implemented by existing test elements.

See [A Comprehensive Guide to Using JMeter Timers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/comprehensive-guide-using-jmeter-timers) article for more detailed information on existing JMeter Timers types.

---

Also consider switching to [JSR223 Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Timer) and [Groovy language](http://groovy-lang.org/) as Groovy performance is much better and Groovy supports latest Java features (and adding some more "syntax sugar" on top of it.